# BIRT in Eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee, birt

Am using BIRT for the first time. I am trying to install MySql JDBC  driver. Navigated to the jar file in plugin folder, I select it but there is nothing in drivers option. Confused, frustrated please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got your jar file, it should just be a matter of setting up the driver with your datasource.

When you create a new report, you create a datasource.  One of the options is Manage Drivers...

[image]

From this screen, you can add your MySQL driver by clicking Add...
[image]

Then you point it to your .jar file, and you should be good to go.

You should only have to do this one time.  After that it should be available in the dropdown for any other report/datasource.